# Code required for a walk cycle? XNA Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

So I just started learning C# code a few months ago and I want to get a sprite in a full walk cycle.

I've got my walk cycle on a PNG image. Which is obviously a series of separate images showing the different stages of a walk cycle. Now I've got that into my Project/Solution I'm doing it as a Windows Game 4.0 in visual studio 2010.

And I'm fairly far on, so I've started trying to do srcRect and destRect set up. But all i've managed to get on screen is the image flicking left to right very fast and then infinitely going right. I achieved this by using the srcRect.X += srcRect.width line.

But what I want to do is have this move much slower. I want the destRect to move right on the screen when the thumbstick is pushed right and as this is happening I want it to flick right through my walk cycle.

I'm getting very muddled and I'm a beginner so any help with this would be great appreciated! Below is my code so far!

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace fra_walk
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        GamePadState pad1, oldpad1;

        Rectangle srcRect;

        struct Rect
        {
        public Rectangle destRect;
        public Rectangle frame;
        public Point velocity;

        }
            Rect destRect;

        struct Wright
        {
            public Texture2D txr;
            public Rectangle frame;
        }

        Wright walkright;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";


            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            destRect.velocity = new Point(0, 0);

            destRect.frame = new Rectangle(400, 400, 83, 170);

            srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 170);

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);



            walkright.txr = Content.Load<Texture2D>("walk right");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit


            GamePadState pad1 = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);


            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            srcRect.X += srcRect.Width;

        //  if ((pad1.ThumbSticks.Left.X == 1.0f)
         //     && (oldpad1.ThumbSticks.Left.X == 1.0f))
       //   {
                // srcRect.X += destRect.frame.Width;
        //  }

            oldpad1 = pad1;
            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(walkright.txr, destRect.frame, srcRect, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: This is actually a very common element in XNA projects. If you google for "xna sprite strip tutorial" you should turn up some very in-depth tutorials.

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip. I was struggling on what exactly to google! I will give this a go right away and see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do what you're wanting would probably be to implement a counter.

Add something like public double animCounter = 0 to the top of your code.

Then around the srcRect.X += srcRect.Width; line add something to the effect of:

```
        if (animCounter > 0)
        {
            animCounter -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        else
        {
            srcRect.X += srcRect.Width;
            animCounter = 0.5f;
        }
```

Again, this is the easy way to do what you're wanting to do, but not necessarily the best. For one, += srcRect.Width will quickly exceed the width of your sprite sheet, so you'd need to check for that and correct it. As itsme86 suggested, you should search Google for some tutorials.

This one isn't a bad start:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203866.aspx